# Azure App Service - Nodejs ES Module Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

Trying to host a simple nodejs api server on azure app service, but getting the following error when azure tries to deploy it

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js from D:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename server.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from D:\home\site\wwwroot\package.json.
```

Checked the azure app service, WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION is set to ~14, and the installed nodejs version is v14.15.0 in the web app. Don't think this version of node has problem with import export anymore.

The code runs perfectly fine locally with either

```
node server.js 
# or
node --experimental-modules server
```

Not sure why it is failing in azure

**My code is below:**

server.js

```js
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

let port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
let router = express.Router(); 

// Middleware to use for all requests
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next();
});

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'Default home page for the api!' });
});

app.use('/api', router);

// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
app.listen(port);

console.log(`Server up and running on port ${port}`);
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "my_package",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node --experimental-modules server",
      "test": "mocha"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
      "express": "^4.17.1"
    }
  }
```

However, if I change the import & export to require, then it will run in azure web app, it seems like perhaps azure iisnode is not compatible with emac6 yet? Anyone knows?

Anyone has any work around of this beside using babel to transpile emac6 down to emac5? As I have having some problem with executing and running the transpiled emac5 code.

Thankz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `"type": "module"` in `package.json` file. It work for me.

```
{
  "name": "module-error",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --experimental-modules server",
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module"
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Ohhh Can you show your sample code without sensitive information. Because I follow your description and cannot reproduce the problem you mentioned.

Comment: Everything is in the post, are you able to open and navigate to the url?

Comment: @Ohhh Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: unfortunately no lollz, I transpiled the code from ES6 to ES5 and found it is still lacking some program I need, so I changed from App Service to azure VM instead lolzz. But thanks for the help :) appreciated

Answer (score 7):

This can be solved by adding a new file next to your `server.js` and configuring it as the app service's (or more specifically iisnode's) entry point (see your `web.config`).

Let's call the new file `run.cjs` and put only the following line into it:

```js
import("./server.js");
```

The `cjs` file extension is important because it tells Node that this file is not a ES module, as it would expect because of `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`. This allows other CommonJS files to include our new file - namely iisnode's `interceptor.js`.
It again imports the `server.js` which then runs fine as ES module.